# ActionScript 3.0 - Collision Between Differents MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, collision

Hello when I hit the player1 with the other player2 works.

```
    if(player1.hitTestObject(player2)){
       collision = true;
}
```

But the player1 has a lot of movieclips of attacks inside the movieclip. If I choose an attack to collide with player 2, doesn't work.

```
    if(player1.punch.hitTestObject(player2)){
       collision = true;
}
```

**ERROR**: `Cannot Access a Property or Method from a Null Object Reference`. Why does it happen? How would the correct form be?

Comment: please, i need help

Comment: need help, god!

Comment: That means **punch** is not defined as a member of **player1** instance in OOP terms. Also, it would be wise of you to restrain from comments like ones above. Of course you need help if you are here. Stressing out how much you need it won't get you more help, it's exactly the opposite.